# how to call rest api for sandbox paypal for payment verification

Tags: json, api, rest, paypal, paypal-sandbox

Hi am running paypal sample application it runs perfetct (Version 2.0 paypal sdk)
i used my sandbox client id in application 
after successfulle payment it gives me json output

but i want to confirm that payment am confused how i can confirm it
i got some docs where they mention to use REST api of sandbox paypal and chek with it
but i dont know how to do it
below is the link

my problem is i dont know how to call below api on browser i have access token and payment id

https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAYMENT ID\
 -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
 -H "Authorization: Bearer {accessToken}"

when am trying to run it as it is on browser with my input parameter it shows me

{"name":"INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR","message":"An internal service error has occurred","information_link":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/docs/api/#INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR"}

this message please help me out please

Answer (score 0):

Dave from PayPal here.

Sometimes we see that `INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR` when you have made a payment using the same PayPal account for both payer and payee.

And sometimes `INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR` means that the Sandbox server is having a transient problem, in which case trying again after some time has passed will solve the problem.

Might either of these scenarios apply in your case?

Comment: dave i realy want your help am doing one good project  in which i want to add paypal sdk

only because of this issue am unable to go further please help me out from this

Comment: i did as per your suggestion but no response :( from api

Comment: I'm not clear what you have tried. (1) Are you using a different PayPal account for your payer than the one you are using for your payee? (2) What do you mean by "no response from api"? Do you mean that you are still getting the same error message when you tried the original request again? (3) Oh, wait. You are simply entering the string you indicated into your browser? That's not going to work. You need to issue a series of requests from your computer -- first to obtain a OAuth 2.0 accessToken, and then to look up the payment.

Comment: I get the Payment ID   but where do you  get the AccessToken needed for the curl